# d3.js - brushing for coordinated display: timeline focus

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Having trouble with d3 brushing. I am reading data from a JSON file which displays all data on a top timeline (context) and allows brushing for display on a bottom timeline (focus).

The axis is displaying properly but the "rects" are not updating. I have tried to use brush.extent() as a reference the selected subset of the JSON object but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe it is altering the JSON format?

I am truly at a loss here. I've been working from this tutorial:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/typegray/7rwo8ajL/6/. 
Jump to line 2487, pasting in the JSON doc was the only way I could get jsfiddle to work.

Live version available here: http://staff.washington.edu/gegray/core-mi/

```
function d3SessionView() {

    var w = parseFloat(d3.select("#d3SessionOverview").style("width"));
    var h = 204;

    var talkTurns = data.session.talkTurn;
    var selected = talkTurns;

    var bar1Margin = {top: 24, right: 0, bottom: 24, left: 0};
    var bar2Margin = {top: 24, right: 0, bottom: 24, left: 0};
    var bar1Height = (h - bar1Margin.top - bar1Margin.bottom - bar2Margin.top - bar2Margin.bottom) / 2;
    var bar2Height = (h - bar1Margin.top - bar1Margin.bottom - bar2Margin.top - bar2Margin.bottom) / 2;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(talkTurns, function(d) { 
            return d.endTime;
        })])
        .range([0, w]);
    var x2 = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(talkTurns, function(d) { 
            return d.endTime;
        })])
        .range([0, w]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top");
    var x2Axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("top");

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(x)
        .extent([0, d3.max(talkTurns, function(d) {
            return d.endTime / 10;
        })])
        .on("brush", brushed);

    var svg = d3.select("#d3SessionOverview").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    var context = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "context")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + bar1Margin.left + "," + bar1Margin.top + ")");

    var focus = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + bar2Margin.left + "," + (bar1Margin.top + bar1Height + bar1Margin.bottom + bar2Margin.top) + ")");

    x.domain([0, d3.max(talkTurns, function(d) {
        return d.endTime;
    })]);
    x2.domain(x.domain());

    focus.selectAll("rect").data(brush.extent())
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x2(d.startTime);
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
            return x2(d.duration);
        })
        .attr("height", bar1Height)
        .attr("class", function(d) {
            if (d.speaker == "therapist") {
                return "greenFill";
            } else {
                return "blueFill";
            }
        })
        .attr("fill-opacity", function(d) {
            return d.vocalArousal;
        });

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .call(xAxis);

    context.selectAll("rect").data(talkTurns)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.startTime);
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
            return x(d.duration);
        })
        .attr("height", bar1Height)
        .attr("class", function(d) {
            if (d.speaker == "therapist") {
                return "greenFill";
            } else {
                return "blueFill";
            }
        })
        .attr("fill-opacity", function(d) {
            return d.vocalArousal;
        });

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .call(x2Axis);

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x brush")
        .call(brush)
        .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("height", bar1Height / 2);

    function brushed() {
        if (brush.empty()) {
            x2.domain(x.domain());
        } else {
            x2.domain(brush.extent());
        }

        focus.selectAll("rect").data(brush.extent())
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return x2(d.startTime);
            })
            .attr("width", function(d) {
                return x2(d.duration);
            })
            .attr("height", bar1Height)
            .attr("class", function(d) {
                if (d.speaker == "therapist") {
                    return "greenFill";
                } else {
                    return "blueFill";
                }
            })
            .attr("fill-opacity", function(d) {
                return d.vocalArousal;
            });

        focus.select(".x.axis").call(x2Axis);
    }
```

Comment: and thanks in advance for helping out a new bee.

Comment: make a working example of your dataset in a fiddle...its a tough to fix the problem like this...in general perception you don't have an exit function which removes the rect not in brushed area..

Comment: yeah, Cyril. It may well be an exit() issue. I made a jsfiddle just now. Thanks in advance!